# How to override default email templates using Yireo_EmailOverride extension?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have read numerous articles suggesting, I shouldn't modify the core email templates. Instead, most articles have suggested to install [Yireo EmailOverride](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/yireo-emailoverride.html) to easily create email overrides.I want to create overrides so that emails matches the store design.  I have installed the extension, but I am unable to figure out what to do next.

Should I manually copy the core transactional emails to my template design ie app/design/frontend/galio/ma_galio1/template?

I am trying to follow these [steps](https://www.yireo.com/blog/1679-magento-email-overrides)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Yireo blogpost, quoting Jisse himself:

> The EmailOverride extension allows you to copy files to your own
>   themes locale folder. Here is one example, the first line being the
>   original file, the second line being the theme override if your theme
>   is called YOURTHEME:

```
app/locale/en_US/template/email/account_new.html
app/design/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/locale/en_US/template/email/account_new.html
```

I see, you're using the same blogpost as guide. In your case (if the name of your theme is **galio** and you're overriding the **en_US** locale) you should place your email-template override in:

```
app/design/frontend/default/galio/locale/en_US/template/email/
```